# NetBeans always shows same files on startup

Tags: netbeans

I have Netbeans 6.8 on Ubuntu Linux and for a while now everytime I start Netbeans it opens up the same 3 files. How can I make sure the IDE starts without opening any files I am sure did close the last time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have permission to (over)write files in the $HOME/.netbeans directory tree, NetBeans will not be able to update its state. May be you started NetBeans as root user while $HOME was still pointing to your login directory.

Can't verify it at the moment, but I hope, it helps.

Comment: I've chowned the ~/.netbeans folder to <myuser>:user recursively, cleared the cache directory of netbeans (under ~/.netbeans/<version>/var/cache/index/) and made some modifications to the launcher (instead of /bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-6.8/bin/netbeans" I omitted the /bin/sh part) and now it seems to work. Thanks for the tip Klaus!